# Execute statement after return statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("parentpan").style.display == "block") {
        return "You are logged out.";
            Logout();
    }
};
```

I want the `logout()` function to be called after the return statement, is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need them in that order?

Comment: technically returning `"you are logged out."` before logging someone out is lying :)

Comment: You are returning "You are logged out." to a user with a ok/cancel prompt? The onbeforeunload does not act like `window.confirm()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return statement ends a function, you cannot execute code after it. You could do this:

```
ret = "You are logged out.";
Logout();
return ret;
```

Answer (score 15):

You can't execute anything after a return statement.

edit: the `finally` statement allows code execution after a `return` for cleanup purposes.

(This is a good example for an XY-Question: You are asking about Y while never telling us for what X you actually need it).

Comment: @Femaref: Actually, there is.  (`finally`)

Comment: @Femaref You might want to clarify; using timers, event handlers, etc., does allow you to put code in a function that will be executed chronologically after the function has returned.

Comment: @Stuart: That's something different than what I wrote - I wrote explicitly "after a return **statement**". Everything you specified are side-effects of a function and have no bearing on the return statement itself.

Answer (score 10):

A possible and most efficient way is `try-catch-finally`.

> Note that the catch `block` is optional if you have a `finally` block.

```js
try {
  // do something
  return;
} finally {
  // call function after return
}
```

[youtu.be/Is_o_L-ZIS8](https://youtu.be/Is_o_L-ZIS8) might be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

What you need is to execute `Logout` asynchronously. This can be easily achieve in JavaScript by using the `setTimeout` function as others have said. Here's a method I commonly use to call functions asynchronously:

```
Function.prototype.async = function () {
    setTimeout.bind(null, this, 0).apply(null, arguments);
};
```

This method pushes a function call onto the event loop immediately (after `0` ms). Hence the function is executed after the current code completes (which for you is after you return). Here's a simple example of how to use it:

```
alert.async("This will be displayed later.");
alert("This will be displayed first.");
```

Since the first `alert` is called asynchronously it will execute after the second call to `alert`. As simple as preceding your function call with `async`. This is what you would do in your case:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("parentpan").style.display === "block") {
        Logout.async();
        return "You are logged out.";
    }
};
```

What's the disadvantage? Since the function is blocked on the event loop it may never get the chance to execute (hence the user will never logout). Such a situation **may** arise. It usually occurs when the control goes into an infinite loop, or hangs because of a blocking AJAX request.

Good news for you however, this happens on a **very** rare occasion. So don't worry about it. Just use `setTimeout` like everyone else is bantering you to and you'll do just fine. Personally I think you should log out before returning a message that `"You are logged out."`, but it's your application.

Happy New Year. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want something to be executed after the function has returned, you can set a timer:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("parentpan").style.display == "block") {
        setTimeout(Logout, 50); // Logout will be called 50ms later
        return "You are logged out.";
    }
};
```

However, as noted in comments, this is not a good idea for onbeforeunload, as the timer event will not be fired if the page finished unloading first.

Comment: Most modern day browsers will kill the timeout and ignore it when the page loads. Basically a race condition.

Comment: @epascarello - you mean "... when the page *unloads*", no?  And, yeah,  timers can not be relied on to fire as part of the page unloading.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answerers are missing what you are trying to do here. You want `window.onbeforeunload` to act like `window.confirm()`. There is no way to act on the ok action in the onbeforeunload event.

What you would have to do is hook it up on onunload to do the action.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
    return "Your session will be logged out" 
};
window.onunload = function () { 
    logout(); 
}
```

Problem with this is modern day browsers will kill a lot of processes that run in unload/beforeunload to "speed up" the browser so it is faster. So if it is asynchronous, you will have a race condition.

Comment: Thanks @Shmiddty for fixing that, I do not think my morning coffee still has not kicked in. :)

Answer (score 0):

return means you are returning from the execution of the called function.When return statement is executed, system understands that the function execution is over and it will switch to the main program from which the function is called.

In the program, you can see a statement after return.But the system wont check that even.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery in your project you can use defered mechanism. You can return promise object for ongoing tasks like this :

```
function task() {

   var defered = $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(defered.resolve , 5000);
   return defered.promise();

}  

function task2() {

   var defered = $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(defered.resolve , 10000);
   return defered.promise();
}   

function run() {
     return $.when(task(),task2());
}

var promise = run();

promise.done(function(){        
      alert("All tasks has been completed");        
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Primes/bZWrb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to achieve this. Your code should be as below

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("parentpan").style.display == "block") {
        setTimeout(function(){
            Logout();
        }, 0);
        return "You are logged out.";
    }
};
```

This will make sure that `Logout` is executed after return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = 10;
function b(){
    a = 25;
  return;
    function a(){}
}
b();
document.write(a);
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to approach this.
The first one is as [stated above by Bhavsar Japan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949026/4742733)

### 1. Example with `try, catch and finally`

```js
const example1 = () => {
  try {
    return console.log('will execute first')
  } finally{
    console.log('will execute second')
  }
  return 'will never execute'
}

const main = () => {
  const message = example1();
  console.log(message)
}

main()
```

### 2. Example with `Promise.resolve`

```js
const example2 = () => {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => console.log('will execute after return'));
  return 'will execute first'

}

const main = () => {
  const message = example2();
  console.log(message);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just written a way to return a result and then call a callback, like this:

```js
function after_return(result, callback) {
  function returner(resolve) {
    if (!resolve) {
      new Promise((res) => returner(res)).then(callback);
      return result;
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }
  return returner(undefined);
}

function main(a, b) {
  return after_return(a + b, (_) => {
    console.log("DONE");
  });
}
console.log(main(5, 4));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that Logout is a time-intensive process and you want to provide feedback to the user before executing it:

```
setTimeout(Logout,1);
return "You are logged out.";
```