# jQuery .click() does not run function

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [execute statement after return statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102912/execute-statement-after-return-statement-in-javascript)

I have an element that on click triggers an option transfer script that moves options from one `<select multiple>` element to another.  It's then supposed to run a function against what was changed.  Only problem is the function isn't running.

```
$('#cityadd').click(function() {
    return !$('#ucityone option:selected').remove().appendTo('#ucitytwo');
    runPagination();
});
```

The function `runPagination();` isn't running when the element `#cityadd` is clicked.  I don't know if this is a syntax error or what.  This same set up runs with other instances that I have in place.

Answer (score 6):

You have a `return` statement at the first line which would return from that line and will not execute further statements.

The `runPagination()` is an unreachable code.. Move the function above the return statement like below.

```
$('#cityadd').click(function() {
    runPagination();
    return !$('#ucityone option:selected').remove().appendTo('#ucitytwo');
});
```

Comment: I'm surprised he didn't noticed it!

Comment: Is there a way to include the function in with the `return`?  When I take it out, it changes the name in the URL query sting for that `<select multiple>` from `city[]` to `city%5B%5D`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it is being executed after the `return` statement, which will effectively ignore anything that follows, making `runPagination()` unreachable.

```
function PerformX()
{
     return x;
     //Unreachable code here
}
```

In order to actually perform that, just switch the order they are being called in:

```
$('#cityadd').click(function() {
    runPagination();
    return !$('#ucityone option:selected').remove().appendTo('#ucitytwo');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you used [`return`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) before calling `runPagination()`

change your code to :

```
$('#cityadd').click(function() {
    $('#ucityone option:selected').remove().appendTo('#ucitytwo');
    runPagination();
});
```

Comment: Doing that screws up the name array I have to call for the `<select multiple>` to work.  It changes the name in the URL query sting for that `<select multiple>` from `city[]` to `city%5B%5D`.