# scope of the variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

```
function foo(a) {
  function a() {
    return 8;
  }
  return a();
  y = 9;
}
console.log(foo() + " " + y);
```

This gives an undefined error for variable `y`.

```
function foo(a) {
  y = 9;

  function a() {
    return 8;
  }
  return a();
}
console.log(foo() + " " + y);
```

This prints `8 9` in the browser console.

If we declare a variable without the `var` keyword than it becomes global variable.

Why first function does not follow the idea?

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question on Stack Overflow. By _literally_ copy-pasting this question's title in Google, I found the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's nothing to do with variable scope and certainly not a duplicate of that.

Comment: Use strict mode and the second snippet will throw an exception as well. Don't not use `var`, just use `var` in the appropriate scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the first example, you have a `return` statement before the `y = 9` and so the assignment is never reached, leaving it undefined.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates like these. Don't encourage or reward users for doing _no_ research whatsoever.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: Then it's a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102912/execute-statement-after-return-statement-in-javascript). My point is that the OP should really do some research before asking.